# Are Angular aliases global?

Tags: angular

From the docs on [Attribute Directives](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#why-input). It seems like they call these "aliases"

> *The myHighlight property on the left refers to an **aliased** property of the HighlightDirective*, not a property of the template's component.

They're declared like this,

```
@Input('myHighlight') highlightColor: string;
```

How are those alises scoped, and are they global?

Comment: IMO the scope is similar to those without `aliases`. Instead of using it like `<my-component [highlightColor]="yellow"></my-component>`, we now use `<my-component [myHighlight]="yellow"></my-component>`. No scoping changes.

Comment: hey, did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44581866/2545680) help?

Answer (score 0):

No, they are specific to a particular component. Supppose you defined your component input like this:

```
@Input('aliased') p;
```

When Angular parses the template:

```
<my-component [aliased]='3'...>
```

It identifies the component `MyComponent` and checks whether it has `aliased` input. It finds it and writes `3` to the component instance.

If you don't specify the alias, it's translated to this:

```
@Input() p;   -> @Input('p') p
```